# Building a Multi-Port Server : Java

Tags: java, multithreading, ports

I'm trying to build a Multi-port server with threads. I also have a ClientManager class and a Client class. What needs to happen is the user enters a range of ports...say ports 8000-8010. The Server needs to listen at all of those ports for connections. The ClientManager then gets the range of ports and creates a Client instance for each one. The Client then sends messages to the Server in random intervals between 0-1 seconds. After 100 messages are sent by a client, it should disconnect. The server needs to print out how many messages it has received every 5 seconds.

So far I've managed to get the user inputs for the range of ports and then send them over to the ClientManager via Runtime.exec() parameters. Here's my current code for the Server and ClientManager:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Server{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{        
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader userInputReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String lowPortRange = null;
            String highPortRange = null;

            System.out.println("Enter low end of port range:");
            if((lowPortRange = userInputReader.readLine())!=null){
                System.out.println("Low Range: " + lowPortRange);
            }
            System.out.println("Enter high end of port range:");

            if((highPortRange = userInputReader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println("High Range: " + highPortRange);
            }


            int lowPort = Integer.parseInt(lowPortRange);
            int highPort = Integer.parseInt(highPortRange);
            int totalPorts = highPort - lowPort+1;

            System.out.println("Total ports: " + totalPorts);
            System.out.println("...Port numbers...");

            for(int port = lowPort; port<=highPort; port++){
                System.out.println(port);
            }

            System.out.println("Done!");
            System.out.println();

            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java ClientManager " + lowPort + " " + highPort);  

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  
                    String line = null;  
                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
                        System.out.println(line);  
                    }  
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("IOException!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

import java.io.*;

public class ClientManager{
    private int lowPort;
    private int numPorts;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("ClientManager Started.");

        int firstPort = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int lastPort = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        System.out.println("First Port: " + firstPort);
        System.out.println("Last Port: " + lastPort);
    }

}
```

My question is basically this: Could someone explain, theoretically, where I should go from here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one ServerSocket for every port you're listening on. Because accept() blocks until a client connects, you'll need to create one thread to listen on each ServerSocket. If more than one client may be connected to a given port at the same time (doesn't seem that way from your description), you'll also have to create one thread for every client connection. And one more to print and zero the message count every 5 seconds – this might as well be the main thread.

Of course, access to the message count will have to be properly synchronised, and the description doesn't mention when the server should shut down if it has to be done gracefully at all.

(Sidenote: not accepting new connections while a client is connected is obviously unacceptable in a "real" server, and one-thread-per-client is not the optimal way to avoid this if you have many clients.)

Comment: Then you'll also have to make sure all of the threads have a shutdown condition of some sort instead of looping forever - the main thread when no more server socket threads exist, the server threads when they finish handling a client connection.

Answer (score 0):

See [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/.../ThreadPoolExecutor.html) for more Info. It will make your sever robust. And you can structure it to suit your demands. If you have never worked it with Executors, not at all an issue. very simple. You will have to just give it Runnable which you need to process, in this case once you get the connection, then the interaction with client etc. Most of your load will get reduced.